# Homeomorphism between Z and Z×Z.

Tags: general-topology

My question is in the context of topological spaces. From the definition in Wikipedia:
A function $ f:X\to Y$ between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism if it has the following properties:

${\displaystyle f}$ is a bijection (one-to-one and onto),
${\displaystyle f}$ is continuous,
the inverse function ${\displaystyle f^{-1}}$ is continuous ($f$ is an open mapping).

How does this relate to Homeomorphism between $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$?

Comment: It does not.${}$

Comment: homeomorphism $\neq$ homomorphism.

Comment: Homeomorphism is for topological spaces; homomorphism is for algebraic structures (e.g., groups)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Though for algebraic structures you would call it isomorphism, I think. ;)

Comment: @gae. : An isomorphism is the algebraic analogue to the homeomorphisms of topological spaces, but it is common to refer to homomorphisms, too. A homomorphism does not require injectivity or surjectivity, only that the algebraic structure is preserved.

Comment: Right, an isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism

Comment: Which topology do you consider on $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove two equinumerous discrete spaces are homeomorphic and apply that theorem to your problem.